# WCF XML WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare equivalent in .NET Core

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am currently in the process of porting a .NET Framework 4.6.2 application to .NET Core 3.1. This application hosts a WCF service that passes XML data between the server and the client. I need to get the same interface/data structures in the .NET Core version, as I am not able to update all clients and the transition needs to be smooth without required changes to the clients.

For the purpose of this question I have stripped down my entire interface to the bare essence of the method that is posing me problems.

The clients send the following XML payload to the method:

```
<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">104</int>
```

The WCF interface in .NET Framework is defined as follows:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface WcfServiceInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Processes an integer value sent in an XML body.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="theInt">The integer to process.</param>
    /// <returns>True if success, false otherwise</returns>
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    bool ProcessInteger(int theInt);
}
```

In .NET Core 3.1 the class handling the WCF is defined as follows:

```
[ApiController]
[Produces("application/xml")]
[Route("wcf")]
public class WcfServiceInstance : ControllerBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Processes an integer value sent in an XML body.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="theInt">The integer to process.</param>
    /// <returns>True if success, false otherwise</returns>
    [Route(nameof(ProcessInteger))]
    public bool ProcessInteger([FromBody] int theInt)
    {
        // ... do something intelligent with the integer
    }
}
```

For the .NET Framework 4.6.2 vrsion everything is working fine. However, when a client calls the same method (with the same message payload) on the .NET Core version of the server application, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 66).
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <int xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'> was not expected.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationPrimitiveReader.Read_int()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.DeserializePrimitive(XmlReader xmlReader, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlSerializerInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.XmlSerializerInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this exception?

The service is instantiated this way in my .NET Core application:

```
using (IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().
                         ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                                 {
                                     webBuilder.UseUrls(@"http://localhost:8080").
                                                UseStartup<WcfStartup>().
                                                UseShutdownTimeout(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
                                 }).
                         Build())
{
    host.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit...");

    Console.ReadLine();
    Task stopTask = host.StopAsync();
    stopTask.Wait();
}
```

The WcfStartup class is defined as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class to startup the WCF service.
/// </summary>
internal class WcfStartup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration
    { 
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures the services.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The service collection to add the required services to.</param>
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
                            {
                                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
                            }).
                 AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing with same html response the client gets?  I do not see a class in your posting with 'int' (or a [XmlRoot(ElementName = "int", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/")], or [XmlElement(ElementName = "int", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"])

Comment: Can I take a look at the XML message sent by your client? How does your client send the XML message? What is the format of the XML message?

Comment: @Dingpeng The entire XML message that is being sent by the client is already in the original post:

<int xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">104</int>

Comment: @jdweng The int type is a base C# integer type. In .NET Framework 4.6.2 this automatically deserializes, because of the "BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml" parameters of the WebInvoke attribute. How should I define a class that just makes it possible to parse this simple integer value?

Comment: Try sending this message:<int>104<int>

Comment: @Dingpeng When I change a test client such that it simply sends the XML declaration without the namespace, it works. However, as I indicated, that requires changing clients using the web service and I need to port the application in such a way that clients to not need to be updated.

Comment: Try [OperationContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization")]

Comment: @jdweng The OperationContract attribute does not have a Namespace property, at least not in .NET Core 3.1. I also tried adding [ServiceContract(Namespace = "schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization")] to the WcfServiceInstance class, but that this not resolve the issue

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: @jdweng I added the following attribute to the ProcessInteger method: [OperationContract(Action = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/ProcessInteger")], but that still leads to the same InvalidOperationException.

Comment: I found Filter in the webapi, and I think you can use Filter to intercept all requests and remove the namespace.

Comment: You do not want to remove the namespace because it is used to validate the input.

Comment: The same error message can occur for different reasons.  In one case you may not need a namespace in another case you may need the namespace.  the only way I found of debugging xml serialize issues is to start commenting out the properties to isolate which class/property is causing the issue.   Start by commenting all properties inside the root class and see if you get an error and you deserialize just the root.  Then start removing the comments to see which property is causing the error.

Comment: @jdweng But in this case, the XML document only contains what is described above. The root IS the <int>-tag with the namespace attribute. The value of the int is being passed to the method ProcesssInteger and there is nothing to comment out, other than the parameter itself. And it is working when the method does not have any parameter...

Comment: @Dingpeng Filtering out namespaces (or other transformations on the input) in my opinion are mere "hacks to make it work". And hacks always bite back at a certain point....

Comment: Try report issue at following.  Owner may have solution : https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackifyMiddleware/3.0.5.2/ReportAbuse